# How to reduce delay in AVplayer for looping audio play - ios swift

Tags: iphone, swift4, avplayer, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I have one mp3 file in project folder which plays again and again, but player makes delay when mp3 is finished. This delay is about 1 second. How do I reduce that delay and replay constantly? I used number of loops but it does not help. Code is below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "finalbreathin", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)



                /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

                //iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

                guard let player = self.player else { return }
                player.numberOfLoops = -1
                self.imageanimate.startAnimating()
                player.play()

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

    }
```

Comment: i already used player number of loops audio is about 9 second long

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1):

I think replay delay main cause each loop declared

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

so move this two line out-off loop or AppDelegate In the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, set the app’s audio session category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.
see more details -> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Comment: i don't get it is it due to AVplayer delegate or AVaudiosessionCategoryplayback?

Comment: please see this url I think you get concept how to implement

Comment: i do it but player cannot match playing time with timer every time 1 second early completed